# How to callback an error message when searching a table is unsuccessful in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently using AWS Lambda JavaScript code to try and search a DynamoDB table this is then implemented into an Amazon Alexa application, but that isn't really important for what I'm asking. Here is the code I'm struggling with:

```
function readDynamoItem(params2, callback) {
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        console.log('reading item from DynamoDB table');

        dynamodb.scan(params2, function (err, data){
            if (err) {
                callback("error");
                //console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            }
            else{
               callback(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

So when an error occurs I want it to callback the message "error" and then use it here:

```
const params2 = {
            TableName: 'Fixtures',
            FilterExpression: 'team1 = :value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": MyQuestion.toLowerCase()}}
};

readDynamoItem(params2, myResult=>{
            say = myResult;
            this.response.speak(say).listen('try again');
            this.emit(':responseReady');
});
```

All I'm getting at the moment is this response when I test, I think due to err just ending the program instead of calling the error back to use in the implementation:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 0f586880-2ddb-11e8-bdf7-07b4c224b25d Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the full code for my project for further reference:

```
const AWSregion = 'eu-west-1';  
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    region: AWSregion
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);

    // alexa.appId = 'amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.1234';
    // alexa.dynamoDBTableName = 'YourTableName'; // creates new table for session.attributes

    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.response.speak('welcome to magic answers.  ask me a yes or no question.').listen('try again');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },


    'MyIntent': function () {
        var MyQuestion = this.event.request.intent.slots.MyQuestion.value;
        console.log('MyQuestion : ' + MyQuestion);


        const params2 = {
            TableName: 'Fixtures',
            FilterExpression: 'team1 = :value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": MyQuestion.toLowerCase()}}
        };
        const params3 = {
            TableName: 'Fixtures',
            FilterExpression: 'team2 = :value',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": MyQuestion.toLowerCase()}}
        };

        readDynamoItem(params2, myResult=>{
            var say = MyQuestion;
            //if nothing is found when scanning for team1, scan team2
            if (myResult == "error"){
                readDynamoItem(params3, myResult2=>{
                    say = myResult2;
                    say = 'The top scorer for ' + MyQuestion + ' is ' + myResult2;
                    this.response.speak(say).listen('try again');
                    this.emit(':responseReady');
                });
            } 
            else{
                say = myResult;
                say = 'The top scorer for ' + MyQuestion + ' is ' + myResult;
                this.response.speak(say).listen('try again');
                this.emit(':responseReady');
            }
        });

    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('ask me a yes or no question.').listen('try again');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};

//  END of Intent Handlers {} ========================================================================================
//  Helper Function  =================================================================================================

//reading the Fixtures table
function readDynamoItem(params2, callback) {
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: AWSregion});

    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    var team1;
    var team2;



    console.log('reading item from DynamoDB table');

    dynamodb.scan(params2, function (err, data){
        if (err) {
            callback("error");
            //callback("error");
            //console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        }
        else{
            console.log(data); // successful response

            team1 = jsonToString(data.Items[0].team1);
            team2 = jsonToString(data.Items[0].team2);
            var t1goals = jsonToString(data.Items[0].t1goals);
            var t2goals = jsonToString(data.Items[0].t2goals);
            t1goals = parseInt(t1goals);
            t2goals = parseInt(t2goals);
            var search;
            var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? team1 : team2;

            // if goals are equal in a match then it is random which team will score next 
            if(t1goals == t2goals){
                search = chosenValue;
            }
            //if a team has 1 goal more than the other then it is a 3rd more likely they will score next
            else if(t1goals > t2goals && t1goals == 1){
                if(randomInt(1, 3) == 1){
                    search = team2;
                }
                else{
                    search = team1;
                }
            }
            else if(t2goals > t1goals && t2goals == 1){
                if(randomInt(1, 3) == 1){
                    search = team1;
                }
                else{
                    search = team2;
                }
            }
            //if a team has more than 1 goal more than the other then it is a 5th more likely they will score next
            else if(t1goals > t2goals && t1goals > 1){
                if(randomInt(1, 5) == 1){
                    search = team2;
                }
                else{
                    search = team1;
                }
            }
            else if(t2goals > t1goals && t2goals > 1){
                if(randomInt(1, 5) == 1){
                    search = team1;
                }
                else{
                    search = team2;
                }
            }

            var params = {
                TableName: 'yesno',
                FilterExpression: 'team = :value',
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {':value': {"S": search}}
            };

            readDynamoFixtures(params, myResult=>{
                callback(myResult);
            });
        }
    });
}

//read player details from the the yesno table
function readDynamoFixtures(params, callback) {
    var goals =  new Array();
    var playing =  new Array();
    var messages =  new Array();
    var most = 0;
    var mostMessage;
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    dynamodb.scan(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    else{
                        for(var i = 0; i <= (data.Count - 1); i++){
                            console.log(data); // successful response
                            var temp = jsonToString(data.Items[i].playername);
                            messages[i] = temp;
                            temp = jsonToString(data.Items[i].goals);
                            temp = parseInt(temp);
                            goals[i] = temp; 
                            temp = jsonToString(data.Items[i].playing);
                            playing[i] = temp;
                            //compare each players goals
                            if (goals[i] > most && playing[i] == "true"){
                                most = goals[i];
                                mostMessage = messages[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }    
                    callback(mostMessage);
                });
}

//convert database items from json format to string
function jsonToString(str){
    str = JSON.stringify(str);
    str = str.replace('{\"S\":\"', '');
    str = str.replace('\"}', '');
    return str;
}

//get a random int between min and max 
function randomInt(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Edit:
I have tried testing this code with .query instead of .scan and the error callback works perfectly which is strange but obviously for this implementation I need to use .scan

Comment: 1. I would suggest using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html instead of DynamoDB().   2. Is it possible that your lambda is timing out? 3. the else block of your code should be callback(null, data) if you're trying to return a successful path

Comment: Yes I'll try changing to document client what's the best parameter to use instead of scan for the document client or does that work the same?? I don't think lambda is timing out as it works fine when there is no error. And the callback after a successful path is just for show I have my own code that I put there just didn't want to make the question too long to explain

Comment: The document client works much the same way, it primarily takes away the need for calling out types (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/).  Try adding a `return` on your callback(...) invocations.

Comment: I've tried using the document client with scan but it doesn't work just gives me the same kind of error even when the params don't return an error. Do you mean just adding return(callback("error"));? That doesn't seem to be working either

Comment: Can you share your entire code?  Because the snippets you've provided aren't giving me enough context to help further.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've added the full code in my question now so hopefully that will help

Answer (score 1):

When you get the "Process exited" response from the Lambda it is helpful to log heavily to see where the Lambda is getting stuck and then check the [Cloudwatch Logs](https://eu-west-3.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-3#logs:) to get to the detail.

Then you can pinpoint the exception and focus on it. At least for me, the root cause was many times unexpected as Lambdas force a different way of thinking.

Comment: Yes I have tried logging like this but all that happens is that after nothing is found instead of calling back the output it does an END request. Here is the logs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'team1' of undefined.      And then: END RequestId: 9f78082f-31dc-11e8-b55a-0df2f95d3cec

Comment: I assume you get that in this line? 
team1 = jsonToString(data.Items[0].team1);
That is usually due to not getting any results back from the query (data = []). You need to check that data.Items[0] exists before accessing the property. If you are not getting anything back it might have to do with your query or the database itself

Comment: Sorry i should have posted that I solved this problem by adding an if statement: if(data.Count == 0){
              callback("error");  
            } this is due to lambda not recognizing that finding nothing is an error and instead just returns the data in an empty json return